# How can I use a <g> tag inside clipPath definition?

Tags: html, svg

This works:

```
<clipPath id="CC1">
<rect x="100" y="700" width="300" height="200"/>
</clipPath>
```

This stops working:

```
<clipPath id="CC1">
<g>
<rect x="100" y="700" width="300" height="200"/>
</g>
</clipPath>
```

In the second case, whatever object the clip path is applied on disappears completely.

Comment: You can't. The SVG spec does not permit it.

Comment: Thanks! I have realized `<pattern>` is the correct way to do it. However it would interesting to know why is `<g>` in `clipPath` not supported in the SVG spec. `transform` attribute is supported on clip paths, so it should be trivial to support `<g>`.

Comment: Only the authors of the specification could tell you that.